# Xcode error when I add a framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, kinvey

When I just add a .framework to the "Link Binary With Libraries" list by dragging it from the Project Navigator to the tab I get an error.

My error...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UAPush", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in KinveyKit(KCSPush.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UAirship", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in KinveyKit(KCSPush.o)
  "_UAirshipTakeOffOptionsAirshipConfigKey", referenced from:
      -[KCSPush initializeUrbanAirshipWithOptions:error:] in KinveyKit(KCSPush.o)
  "_logging", referenced from:
      -[KCSPush application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:] in KinveyKit(KCSPush.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_IVAR_$_KCSLogManager._loggingState, _OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLogger._loggingBehavior )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I remove the .framework, the app runs without errors.

Also when I look inside my Headers folder inside Kinvey.framework, I see header files with red names. Does that have anything to do with the problem perhaps?

Why is this happening??

Comment: Is KCPush one of your project files? Where are the missing symbols (UAPush, etc.) supposed to be?

Comment: KCPush is supposed to be part of the KinveyKit.framework. There is only a Headers folder in the framework group with header files with red names.

Answer (score 2):

UAPush = Urban Airship Push.

Add libUAirship.a to your project.

[Here you can download lib](http://com.urbanairship.filereleases.s3.amazonaws.com/libUAirship-latest.zip).

[Complete Documentation about urban Airship push](http://urbanairship.com/resources/developer-resources)

[Also checkout this urban Airship common error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827119/ios-project-shows-linker-error-for-i386)

Comment: Thanks so much! I missed that instruction. :)