# Adding a custom Framework to an Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch

I decided to try to make a Cocoa Touch Framework. Making it worked fine, but I am having trouble adding it to a project. After searching through *a lot* of SO posts and looking at Apple Forum threads I decided to try this from the Docs:

> Add a framework bundle to a project in order to incorporate the
>   framework’s features into your product.
>
> In the project navigator, select the project or group within a project
>   to which you want to add the framework.
>
> Choose File > Add Files to “”.
>
> Select the framework bundle, and click Add.
>
> The frameworks you add this way are third-party-built bundles
>   containing the framework’s object code and runtime resources. See
>   related articles for information about linking to a framework without
>   adding it to the project.
>
> After you add the framework, Xcode configures the targets in your
>   project to link them to the framework just added.

It still doesn't work. I am getting a `No such module 'Scaffold'` error for everything I try, I have checked spelling, but that is not it. Can someone explain how this works? I might just need clarification on how this is done.

Links I have looked at:

- [Create and import swift framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460998/create-and-import-swift-framework)
- [Xcode error when I add a framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887258/xcode-error-when-i-add-a-framework)
- [Adding a framework to XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972904/adding-a-framework-to-xcode-4)
- [Xcode 5.1 compiler errors after adding a framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923572/xcode-5-1-compiler-errors-after-adding-a-framework)
- [Add a framework to an existing project without using cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907501/add-a-framework-to-an-existing-project-without-using-cocoapods)
- [What is the process for creating a Framework?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16717)

Comment: I had a similar problem with importing frameworks to a playground in a workspace. I solved it by: Preferences > Locations > Derived Data (Default) > Advanced > √Unique (mine was on legacy causing the problem). Also sometimes the framework name can be different than the bundle name, so make sure that's matching.

Comment: @user14492. My project, workspace, and framework are all set to `Unique`. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I do not know if it is too late to answer this question, but due to the fact that I am facing same issues right know I would recommend you to check the Build Settings of the project where you import your framework

You should check the "Framework Search Path" and if the framework is at Swift and you import to an obj c project check YES to "Always embed swift standard libraries"

More or less the problem I think is in the Build Settings